# Strange label as value of html tag inside php file of WordPress template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, xhtml, wordpress-theming

I am quite new in PHP and in WordPress. I am modifying this template:

In some php files I found something like this:

```
<span class="sep">Posted on </span>
                 <a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark">
                    <time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time>

                 </a>
                 <span class="by-author"> 
                    <span class="sep"> by bla</span> 
                    <span class="author vcard">
                        <a class="url fn n" href="%5$s" title="%6$s" rel="author">%7$s</a>
                        <p>CUCU</p>
                    </span>
                    <span>BLABLA</span>
                 </span>
```

As you can see, instead of the values for some tag as href, title, datetime I find some label (like **%1$s**, **%2$s**, **%4$s**)

What it mean and what are reference to?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Those are just placeholders, where variables (some value) will be placed when the page loads. Wordpress uses templates, which is why you are seeing those instead of hard coded values that you would generally see on a regular .html file.

Comment: Ok, but I can't find where are the variables that are put in place  of these placeholders...where can be definied? in a file? I can't find :-/

Comment: It's hard to say where they're defined since I cannot see the whole file, but you don't really need to know where they're defined... In the case that you want to use those values, well then simply copy and paste those variables wherever... It's hard to advise what to do because I don't know what you're trying to do exactly. But just a warning, you can crash your whole site if you're editing PHP files and you make even a slight syntax mistake.